# running protractor test with teamcity

Tags: teamcity, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I want to run my protractor test (remote server) using teamcity project.
I'm new to teamcity. I want to call the scripts from teamcity.

1. can I just refer the script at its location without having 'checkout directory'? since I don't do checkout, I just want to run the scripts and control it remotely.
2. what is the best way to combine protractor tests with teamcity? the target is to make it run on hourly basis and use the results - send it on mail, run again if failed etc.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can run test from teamcity targets without checking out any code. You can leave the vcs settings as blank if you want to .
2. Teamcity targets can automatically send email for test failures to individuals or groups. Normally emails are sent to developers who have commits in a particular run, however since you are not tying in any VCS to your build step, you can sign up a group of people who will receive a mail whenever tests fail using the "Notifications" tab